# VBA copy row from one sheet to another based on 2 criteria

Tags: vba, excel

i have 2 sheeets. basically ws1 is the destination, ws2 is the source. then i have 2 criterias, an ID Number, and a name of the person who will work on the ID Number.

source contains a row with new actions/progress done by "working person" and need to paste it on the destination in order to update it.

I've read around and saw that autofilter looks like the way to go. i have a code here that autofilters, but i'm just not sure how i can "attack" the problem.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrowDest As Long, currow As Long, lastrowSrc As Long
Dim critvalue1 As String


'Destination sheet (dashboard)
Set ws1 = Sheets("Destination")
'Source Sheet (source)
Set ws2 = Sheets("Source")

lastrowSrc = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
lastrowDest = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



For currow = 2 To lastrowSrc

critvalue1 = ws2.Range("E" & currow).Value

ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=critvalue1



Next currow

end sub
```

is there an easy way to copy the row from source to destination provided that the IDnumber matches? (the IDnumber is unique)

the code above filters but i'm not sure of how to copy or move the rows.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use a `VLOOKUP` function? No need for a macro if I understand your problem corretly.

Comment: Your code only shows one criteria where is the other?

Comment: You certainly don't want to put the autofilter code in a loop. You just filter it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with SUMPRODUCT or VLOOKUP but if you are set on VBA then try this

```
Sub copyRow()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrowDest As Long, currowSrc As Long, currowDest As Long, lastrowSrc As Long
Dim critvalue1 As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet1")

lastrowSrc = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row - 1
lastrowDest = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For currowSrc = 2 To lastrowSrc
    critvalue1 = ws2.Range("E" & currowSrc).Value
    ws2.Cells(6, 5).Value = critvalue1
    For currowDest = 2 To lastrowDest
        If ws1.Range("E" & currowDest).Value = critvalue1 Then
           ws2.Rows(currowSrc).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & currowDest)
        End If
    Next currowDest
Next currowSrc

End Sub
```

I find it easier than dealing with the autofilter. It goes row by row from the source sheet and checks for a match in every row of the destination sheet. If there is a match, the source row in copied to the matching destination row.

To keep formatting instead of

```
ws2.Rows(currowSrc).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & currowDest)
```

use

```
ws2.Rows(currowSrc).Copy
ws1.Range("A" & currowDest).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: hi, this looks amazingly quick with results. i have a question with "ws2.Cells(6, 5).Value = critvalue1" about what this does

Comment: Oh sorry I missed taking that out. That was just so I could see the value of `criticalvalue1` for troubleshooting. One other thing I didn't include was `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. This turns off screen updating so the screen doesn't flicker while the code is being run and can greatly increase speed if working over large amounts of data. The false turns off updating so put after the `Set ws2`. The true turns it back on so put it right before `End Sub`.

Comment: the source rows contains formula, i need them to be transferred over to when being copied. any advise?

Comment: Without knowing the formulas I cannot give exact help. I did try this and it does copy the equations. You just need to make sure to lock the cells or it will try to adjust. For example `=SUM(A2:A10)` will change when copied but `=SUM($A$2:$A$10)` will not change where ever it is copied.

Comment: hi, instead of copying the formula and the whole row is there a way i can copy specific columns instead? for example column 34, 35, etc)

Comment: Yeah instead of `ws2.Rows(currowSrc).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & currowDest)` you want to only select the cell you want and put it in a specific destination. Each cell will need its own copy code. You can try `ws2.Range("BB" & currowSrc).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("BB" & currowDest)` Just change the `BB` to whatever column you need.

Comment: hi, it works almost flawlessly. the only issue that i have now is that the formatting of the cells are not carried over after pasting. any advise?

Comment: You can try change the `ws2.Rows(currowSrc).Copy Destination:=ws1.Range("A" & currowDest)` to the edited version above.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this out of a larger macro I use and made some changes to make it match your method a little better and I deleted some irrelevant stuff. The variable names are a bit different. I believe this does what you need. Let me know if it gives you trouble.
Don't forget to populate the ID and Name arrays, set the value for the 2 column variables and assign the sheet names before running.

```
Sub copyByAutofilter()

Dim filterList1 As Variant
    filterList1 = Array("ID1", "ID2")
    filterCol1 = 1 'or whatever column contains the IDs
Dim filterList2 As Variant
    filterList2 = Array("Name1", "Name2")
    filterCol2 = 2 'or whatever column contains the names

Dim sourceWB As String
    sourceWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
Dim sourceWS As String
    sourceWS = "Sheet2"
Dim destinationWB As String
    destinationWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
Dim destinationWS As String
    destinationWS = "Sheet3"

lastrowSrc = Sheets(sourceWS).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
lastrowDest = Sheets(destinationWS).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks(sourceWB).Sheets(sourceWS).AutoFilterMode = False

Workbooks(sourceWB).Sheets(sourceWS).Range("$A$1:$O" & lastrowSrc).AutoFilter Field:=filterCol1, _
        Criteria1:=filterList1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Workbooks(sourceWB).Sheets(sourceWS).Range("$A$1:$O" & lastrowSrc).AutoFilter Field:=filterCol2, _
        Criteria1:=filterList2, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Workbooks(sourceWB).Sheets(sourceWS).Range("A2:O" & lastrowSrc).SpecialCells _
        (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Workbooks(destinationWB).Sheets(destinationWS).Cells(lastrowDest + 1, 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is by using the `Copy` method of the `Range` object. This should generally be avoided though as this overwrites the clipboard. A safer option is to simply use `rngDest.Value = rngSrc.Value`. Note that for this to work the ranges must be the same size. Here is how this is normally used:

```
Dim dst As Range
Dim src As Range
Set src = Range("A1:B3") 'Data you want to copy 
Set dst = Range("C1") 'First cell in the destination Range
Set dst = dst.Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count) 'Resize to match src
dst.Value = src.Value 'Copy to destination
```

This method has the benefit of preserving the clipboard!